# Is call/cc a copy of a stack frame or an actual jump in execution?

Tags: scheme, infinite-loop, continuations, continuation-passing, callcc

I don't understand how the following does not set up an infinite loop:

```
(define call/cc call-with-current-continuation) ; ccc alias
(define return #f) ; declare a global variable 'return'

(+ 1 (call/cc (lambda (cont) ; setup continuation with 'cont' as the exit procedure
                (set! return cont) ; set global var 'return' to the exit procedure
                1))) 

(return 22) ; 23
```

When I call `(return 22)`, I jump back to the continuation, but with the passed value, 22, as the new evaluated result of the `call/cc` form.  Would that not result in `(return 22)` being evaluated as the next statement, thus setting up an infinite loop?

I know it is not an infinite loop, but I do not understand why it is not.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529475/scheme-continuations-for-dummies/16531429#16531429) helps.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* an infinite loop. However, in most Scheme implementations, top-level forms are evaluated in [prompts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._prompt-model%29).

If you put your expressions inside a `(let () ...)`, say, you'll definitely see the infinite loop in effect.