# Call Continuation CC in Scheme

Tags: scheme, callcc, continuation

I'm completly lost with the call continuation in Scheme. Can someone help me with this example ?

```
 #lang scheme


(define a-continuation '*dummy-value*)

(define (myfunction what? l)
  (cond ((null? l) 0)
        ((what? (car l)) 
         (+ 1 (call/cc (lambda (f)
                         (set! a-continuation f)
                         (myfunction what? (cdr l))))))
        (else (myfunction what? (cdr l)))))

(myfunction number? '(18 16 2015 2))

(a-continuation 2014)
```

I understand the first result (3) but I don't understand the result 2017.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16529475/849891) helps.

Answer (score 3):

I get this

```
> (myfunction number? '(18 16 2015 2))
4
> (a-continuation 2014)
2018
```

but this "to the best of my knowledge" explanation should still work.

(I expected the continuation to add 1 to its argument. I was wrong, so I'm trying to explain this to myself, too.)

If you remove the continuation parts, `myfunction` is a function that counts for how many elements the predicate `what?` holds.

Playing around a little in the REPL/interaction window,

```
> (myfunction number? '(1))
1
> (a-continuation 1)
2
> (a-continuation 2)
3

> (myfunction number? '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
10
> (a-continuation 1)
11
> (a-continuation 2)
12
> (a-continuation 3)
13

> (myfunction even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
5
> (a-continuation 1)
6
> (a-continuation 2)
7
> (a-continuation 3)
8
```

One can suspect from this pattern that the continuation adds to its argument the number of elements that `myfunction` found.

This is my explanation of why this is so:

If you view each `call/cc` as a "hole" that you can fill in later by calling the captured continuation, the first one is

```
(+ 1 <hole>)
```

the second

```
(+ 1 (+ 1 <hole>))
```

and so on, creating a "chain" of additions, one for each time the predicate holds.
(I.e. capturing the entire recursion that's "waiting" for the continuation to continue, not just the innermost call.)

So

```
(myfunction number? '(18 16 2015 2))
```

creates something that looks like

```
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 <hole>))))
```

and when you call the continuation,

```
(a-continuation 2014)
```

you evaluate

```
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 2014))))
```

which is, of course, 2018.

(Disclaimer: *This may be completely wrong.*)

Comment: You are right @molbdnilo. In call/cc, `f` is a procedure which takes one argument. And that argument is the return value. When you call the procedure you  (bound to `a-continuation`) it will return it's argument `2014` in your example. And this will be evaluated above. The only thing you are forgetting is the `0` `myfunction` returns when called on the `null?` list.

Answer (score 0):

This can be really confusing. But maybe a simpler example can help (taken from [here](http://community.schemewiki.org/?call-with-current-continuation):

```
(define return #f) 

(+ 1 (call/cc 
       (lambda (cont) 
         (set! return cont) 
         1))) ;; <--- (+ 1 1)
 > 2
 (return 22)
 > 23
```

When you evaluate the `(+ 1 (call/cc ...))` You get `2`. Because the return value of the `(call/cc ...)` part is `1`. Now we have set `return` to be `cont` in `call/cc`. In this scope, `cont` is a procedure that takes 1 argument. And when called, it will evaluate to that argument. Here is the interesting part, when you evaluate the procedure, evaluation is resumed at the spot of the `call/cc`. So when you call `(return 22)` It will evaluate to `22` up there in `(+ 1 (call/cc ...))`, resulting in `23`.

Hope this is clear. In the page I linked to there are other more complex examples.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your example, but I don't understand mine. I'd think that I shoud have (+ 1 ( 2014), so 2015 but I get 2018.

Comment: the execution of `myfunction` continues. Every loop you set `a-continuation` tu a new value. So for each recursion you get `(+ 1 ...)` and the last recursion gets 0. So you add 2014 to a 1 for each element for which `what?` is true.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `(myfunction number? '(18 16 2015 2))` you will have `a-continuation` set to the continuation of each iteration and the last one when it has processed `18`, `16`, and `2015` and processing `2`.

When calling `(a-continuation 2014)` you go back to the processing of `2` but instead of recursing you tell the answer to the continuation is `2014`, thus you get `(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 2014)))) ; ==> 2018`