# Execute the following call/cc expression

Tags: scheme, racket, evaluation, continuations, callcc

I use racket and I got the result `4` for following simple code:

```
(let/cc done
  ((let/cc esc
     (done (+ 1 (let/cc k
                  (esc k)))))
   3))
```

and I was going to execute this code step-by-step.

First, I changed the first `let/cc` into the form of `call/cc` like below:

```
(call/cc (λ (done)
           ((let/cc esc
              (done (+ 1 (let/cc k
                           (esc k)))))
            3)))
```

Of course, this produces `4` also.

Second, since I found the mechanism of `call/cc` in the [internet](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/15-scheme-continuations.html) which says `call/cc` do following 4 steps:

1. Captures the current continuation.
2. Constructs a function `C` that takes one argument, and applies the current continuation with that argument value.
3. Passes this function as an argument to `expr` --- i.e., it invokes `(expr C)`.
4. Returns the result of evaluating `(expr C)`, unless `expr` calls `C`, in which case the value that is passed to `C` is returned.

Thus, I followed above steps for the first `call/cc` like:

1. Current continuation is an identity.
2. `C` refers `(λ (x) x)`.
3. Since `expr` is `(λ (done) ((let/cc esc (done (+ 1 (let/cc k (esc k))))) 3))`, `(expr C)` is:

   ```
   ((λ (done)
      ((let/cc esc
         (done (+ 1 (let/cc k
                      (esc k)))))
       3))
    (λ (x) x))
   ```
4. To return the result value of above code, I execute above in racket.

But, above code (modified by me) is not executed and produces an error:

> ```
> > application: not a procedure;
> >
> > expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
> >
> >  given: 4
> >
> >  arguments...:
> >
> >   3
> ```

Please what I did wrong. I'm confusing the concept of continuation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuations are not just closures (functions). They also perform a *jump* to their defining location in code. You have to perform the CPS transformation in full to try evaluating the resulting expression in Scheme interpreter. That expression will only contain `lambda`s and no continuations (in the sense of `call/cc` <sup>**(1)**</sup>).

The expression that you tried mixes them both - it defines `done` as simple `lambda`-defined function, but it is still used in the nested context as a continuation.

---

**(1)** (another source of confusion is calling the function arguments in the continuation-passing style "continuations". they are ***not*** "true" continuations; they are simple functions "to be called" in this or that eventuality, so colloquially they are also referred to as "continuations" although "contingencies" or even "handlers" could be better.)

See also [another example of call/cc code translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529475/scheme-continuations-for-dummies/16531429#16531429).

Following that approach, translating your Scheme code into Common Lisp, we get:

```
;; (let/cc done
;;   ((let/cc esc
;;      (done (+ 1 (let/cc k
;;                   (esc k)))))
;;    3)) 
(prog  (retval done arg1 func esc arg2 k arg3 arg4)
    (setq done (lambda (x) (setq retval x) (go DONE)))    ; 3
     (setq arg1 3)                                        ; 5
      (setq esc  (lambda (x) (setq func x) (go ESC)))     ; 8
       (setq arg3 1)                                      ; 10
        (setq k  (lambda (x) (setq arg4 x) (go K)))       ; 12
        (setq arg4 (funcall esc k))                       ; 13
  K                                                       ; 11  continuation K
       (setq arg2 (+ arg3 arg4))                          ; 9
      (setq func (funcall done arg2))                     ; 7
  ESC                                                     ; 6   continuation ESC
     (setq retval (funcall func arg1))                    ; 4
  DONE                                                    ; 2   continuation DONE
    (return retval))                                      ; 1
```

which indeed [returns 4](http://ideone.com/HiVaJQ) (the lines of code are numbered in order as they are written, during the translation).

Answer (score 1):

When the interpreter sees a `call/cc` even the interpreters that doesn't do CPS does it with that subtree. Your code would look something like this:

```
((λ (done)
   ((λ (esc)      
      ((λ (k) (esc k))
       (λ (r) (k+ done 1 r))))
    (λ (v) (v 3))))
 values)


; k+ implementation (+, but CPS) 
(define (k+ k . args)
  (k (apply + args)))
```